# Refresh Excel workbook with data from SQL Azure Database in SharePoint Online

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, sharepoint-online

I am migrating from an on-prem SQL database and on-prem SharePoint server to Azure SQL Database and SharePoint Online.

In the current setup I have a SharePoint library containing Excel files that contain data from the SQL database. The connection is defined in an odc file. Excel Services Authentication is setup in this odc using a stored account. This allows data refresh from Excel Web App.

I am trying to setup the same thing in our new environment, but can't find any information on how to set it up. I have tried creating an excel file with a connection to the Azure SQL database and uploading that into a document library in SharePoint Online. If I open the workbook in the browser and click refresh data I get an error saying unable to refresh one or more data connections. If I open in the Desktop App then I can refresh without any issues. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible or do I need to rethink the setup?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database is not supported. Azure SQL Managed Instance is supported with SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019. See all the [SQL Server options for SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/sql-server-and-storage).

For SharePoint online you need Business Connectivity Services (BCS) to connect with data services and although the following document: [Manage Business Connectivity Service Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-business-connectivity-service-applications) references Azure SQL Database, I believe that Azure SQL Managed Instance is supported but not Azure SQL Database. SQL Managed Instance is a full featured SQL Server instance on an Azure VM. SQL Database is a PaaS service with a subset of SQL Server functionality.